# Loading image from cache using BitmapFactory.decodeStream() in Android

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, bitmapimage

**UPDATES**: Even if i don't retrieve images from cache, i tried to retrieve via Drawable where i stored all the 18 images in the "drawable-mdpi" folder. Still, a blank screen was display.

I was able to retrieved images from the server and save the image (.GIF) into the cache. However, when i need to load that image from cache, the image doesn't show up on screen. Here is the codes that does the work:

```
    File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

            File cacheMap = new File(cacheDir, smallMapImageNames.get(i).toString());
            if(cacheMap.exists()){
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(cacheMap);
                    Bitmap local = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                    puzzle.add(local);  
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }else{
                Drawable smallMap = LoadImageFromWebOperations(mapPiecesURL.get(i).toString());
                if(i==0){
                    height1 = smallMap.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    width1 = smallMap.getIntrinsicWidth();
                }
                if (smallMap instanceof BitmapDrawable) { 
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)smallMap).getBitmap();
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        cacheMap.createNewFile();
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheMap);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                        fos.flush();       
                        fos.close(); 
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }       

                    puzzle.add(bitmap);
                }
            }
```

ArrayList to store the image names: **smallMapImageNames** (The image names can also be found in the URL)

ArrayList to store the URL of the images: **mapPiecesURL**

To sum it up i have 2 questions
1) how to load images from cache?
2) regarding the bitmap.compress(), the images from the server is .GIF format but i apply Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG. So is there going to be any problem with this?

Can anyone please help me with this?

**The two functions**

```
    private Bitmap getBitMap(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WifiPositioningServices wifiPositioningServices = new WifiPositioningServices();

        String[] mapURLandCalibratedPoint1 = wifiPositioningServices.GetMapURLandCalibratedPoint("ERLab-1_1.GIF","ERLab"); //list of map pieces url in the first 9 pieces
        String[] mapURLandCalibratedPoint2 = wifiPositioningServices.GetMapURLandCalibratedPoint("ERLab-4_1.GIF","ERLab"); //list of map pieces url in the last 9 pieces
        ArrayList<String> smallMapImageNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mapPiecesURL = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i<mapURLandCalibratedPoint1.length; i++){
                if(mapURLandCalibratedPoint1[i].length()>40){ //image url
                    int len = mapURLandCalibratedPoint1[i].length();
                    int subStrLen = len-13;
                    smallMapImageNames.add(mapURLandCalibratedPoint1[i].substring(subStrLen, len-3)+"JPEG");
                    mapPiecesURL.add(mapURLandCalibratedPoint1[i]);
                }
                else{
                    //perform other task
                }

        }

        for(int i=0; i<mapURLandCalibratedPoint2.length; i++){
            if(mapURLandCalibratedPoint2[i].length()>40){ //image url
                int len = mapURLandCalibratedPoint2[i].length();
                int subStrLen = len-13;
                smallMapImageNames.add(mapURLandCalibratedPoint2[i].substring(subStrLen, len-3)+"JPEG");
                mapPiecesURL.add(mapURLandCalibratedPoint2[i]);
            }
            else{
                //perform other task
            }       
        }
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(1029, 617, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        ArrayList<Bitmap> puzzle = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        int height1 = 0 ;
        int width1 = 0;

        File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

        for(int i=0; i<18; i++){                
            File cacheMap = new File(cacheDir, smallMapImageNames.get(i).toString());
            if(cacheMap.exists()){
                //retrieved from cached
                try {           
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cacheMap);                
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                    puzzle.add(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }else{
                //retrieve from server and cached it
                Drawable smallMap = LoadImageFromWebOperations(mapPiecesURL.get(i).toString());
                if(i==0){
                    height1 = smallMap.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    width1 = smallMap.getIntrinsicWidth();
                }
                if (smallMap instanceof BitmapDrawable) { 
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)smallMap).getBitmap();
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        cacheMap.createNewFile();
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheMap);
                        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                        fos.flush();       
                        fos.close(); 
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }       

                    puzzle.add(bitmap);
                }
            }       
        }

        Rect srcRect;
        Rect dstRect;
        int cnt =0;


        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            int newHeight = height1 * (j % 3);
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                if (j == 0 && k == 0) {
                    srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, width1, height1);
                    dstRect = new Rect(srcRect);
                } else {
                    int newWidth = width1 * k;
                    srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, width1, height1);
                    dstRect = new Rect(srcRect);
                    dstRect.offset(newWidth, newHeight);
                }
                canvas.drawBitmap(puzzle.get(cnt), srcRect, dstRect,null);
                cnt++;
            }
        }

        for(int a=0; a<3; a++){
            int newHeight = height1 * (a % 3);
            for (int k = 3; k < 6; k++) {
                if (a == 0 && k == 0) {
                    srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, width1*3, height1);
                    dstRect = new Rect(srcRect);
                } else {
                    int newWidth = width1 * k;
                    srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, width1, height1);
                    dstRect = new Rect(srcRect);
                    dstRect.offset(newWidth, newHeight);
                }
                canvas.drawBitmap(puzzle.get(cnt), srcRect, dstRect,
                        null);
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exc="+e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am actually trying to display 18 pieces (3X6) of images to form up a floorplan. So to display the images, i use two for-loop to display it. the two .GIF images, ERLab-1_1.GIF and ERLab-4_1.GIF are the center piece of each group. For example, the first row of would be ERLab-0_0.GIF, ERLab-1_0.GIF, ERLab-2_0.GIF, ERLab-3_0.GIF, ERLab-4_0.GIF, ERLab-5_0.GIF. Second row would be XXX-X_1.GIF and XXX-X_2.GIF for the third row.

Lastly,

```
Bitmap resultMap = getBitMap(this.getContext());
bmLargeImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(1029 , 617, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bmLargeImage = resultMap;
```

Then in the onDraw function would be drawing the image onto the canvas.

Comment: sorry, that i forgotten to mention this. It is just another ArrayList to store all the Bitmap images after retrieving them from cache (if images are already available in cache) or from the server.

Comment: `decodeStream` is successfully returning a bitmap?

Comment: i don't think so cause i added in the following lines to test whether the bitmap is null.
           if (bitmap != null)
            puzzle.add(bitmap);
             else{
                 Log.e("onCreate: ", "bMap es NULL");
             }
Nothing shows up so it means there is images being retrieved but something else is wrong somewhere?

Comment: now i am getting null value for decodeStream.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved my own question.

In this line, `canvas.drawBitmap(puzzle.get(cnt), srcRect, dstRect,null);` within each of the for-loop which i am using it to draw the bitmap onto the canvas, i need to cast the each item in the ArrayList (puzzle) to Bitmap. Only then will the image get display.

I thought that if the ArrayList is definite as such, `ArrayList<Bitmap> puzzle = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();` each items in the ArrayList would be of Bitmap type. But isn't that always true?