# BitmapFactory decode function for Android

Tags: android, caching, bitmap

I encounter problem with `.decodeStream` function.

```
File cacheMap = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "test.GIF");

if(cacheMap.exist()){
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(cacheMap);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    puzzle.add(test);
}else{
 //retrieved from server and cache the image
}
```

The decode function always return null value. And from the internet, I found that in order to display the image, the Bitmap is always set to an ImageView. But what I am doing here is storing it into a ArrayList of Bitmap and display it later on in a Canvas. Can anyone tell me how to get back the image after decoding it?

From this [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html), it states the following,

`public static Bitmap decodeStream (InputStream is)`

Decode an input stream into a bitmap. If the input stream is null, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the function returns null. The stream's position will be where ever it was after the encoded data was read.

**Parameters**: The input stream that holds the raw data to be decoded into a bitmap.

**Returns**:The decoded bitmap, or null if the image data could not be decoded."

Does it means that the image that was cached previously cannot be use to decode it even though I had run the few line of code to cached the image?

```
cacheMap.createNewFile();
fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheMap);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
fos.flush();       
fos.close();
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code? i have been tackling this issue for days and is driving me crazy!

Comment: Did you check your file stored normally? check the size of your image file. My code is not that different from yours. I just close input stream.

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
Util.closeQuietly(fis); // this is my utility method

Comment: actually the image dimension is 171X205, and file size isn't that big. as for whether it is store normally, i was able to locate the files in the DDMS, with the following directory: data/data/*package name*/cache/test.GIF so i guess is stored properly in the cache.

Comment: @kingori inside your utility method, you just close the FileInputStream that was pass in as parameter?

Comment: yes, I just close input stream. my code is not that different from yours. So, I think that your code is ok. is there any other exceptions?

Comment: nv encounter any exception but just that the bitmap that was retrieved from cache sometimes return null which causes the program to Force Close or it did return something but display nothing resulting in a black screen.

Comment: I just solve [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543928/loading-image-from-cache-using-bitmapfactory-decodestream-in-android/7566525#7566525)