# Assigning GIF data to Bitmap object

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

I've read in numerous places that Android does not have native gif support. As a result, my code is failing on `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`. Here's my code:

```
URL url = new URL(imgURL); //you can write here any link
HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);          

ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
int current = 0;
  while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
  baf.append((byte) current);
}

image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baf.toByteArray(), 0, baf.toByteArray().length);
```

Using the debugger I confirmed the header data is loaded properly and is of GIF format. But once the decode function runs I'm left with a null value. My first guess is that I need to do a GIF -> PNG conversion. How can I do this? Are there other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So despite Android complaining about the GIF and decode failing I think the issue resided through other failures in my code. Changes I made which cause the code to now work.

1. Made sure I closed the input stream
2. Removed an incident which could cause infinite looping and thread generation (this was a failure on my parsing rules that pulled out the list of GIF files from an HTML source)
3. Ensured my storage of the `Bitmap` files in a `List` object were always properly casted before being used.

I found help and details through [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553431/bitmapfactory-decode-function-for-android) which was an almost identical issue. There are links that follow through on the issue.

In the end I didn't touch my Bitmap or InputStream objects at all, the data was being received properly (as per my confirmation with the GIF header bytes) but was a failure of *using* the data afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The GifView class at http://code.google.com/p/android-gifview/ works well. That project is intended for animated gifs, however it works fine with static gifs as well.

Comment: I'll have to check that out. I was hoping for not needing additional libraries but if its what I need to do...